# SQL Server Round Function Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I'm using SSMS 2014, I got an issue on rounding up the column (`FLOAT`) in my `SampleTable`. If you'll notice on the below rounding the 7.725 should be 7.73 but the output is 7.72 which is wrong. Hope you can help me fix this issue.

CODE

```
SELECT date, ROUND(timeelapsed, 2) AS RoundedValue, timeelapsed 
FROM SampleTable
```

OUTPUT

```
date        RoundedValue    timeelapsed
----------------------------------------
2020-02-03  2.78            2.781944445
2020-02-05  0.43            0.433333333
2020-02-06  8.67            8.670833334
2020-02-07  5.78            5.783055556
2020-02-08  2.43            2.431111111
2020-02-09  7.72            7.725
2020-02-10  4               3.996388889
```

Comment: I have tested the same timeelapsed value. It returns 7.73. I don't see any issue.

Comment: [I *can* replicate your issue](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b50937dda7a93f9833190c8b95c31e74), however, then the *real* (pun intended) problem is your choice of data type. Both `real` and `float` are imprecise numbers, and so you can (and should) expect behaviour like this. For something like "time", `float`/`real` feels like the wrong data type and an `int` (or `bigint`) is normally a better data type; where `1` dentoes the lowest required denominator (i.e. a Second or millisecond).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. The issue is on the values with 3 decimal points, seems SQL didn't consider the 3rd number on rounding off.

Comment: It does, @WalterWhite , if you use a precise data type. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7ef0f6579cd64f21e36eccbda18500c) `real`/`float` is the problem here, not `ROUND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that 7.725 cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number.

In other words the float value is slightly smaller than 7.725, and since this is closer to 7.72 than 7.73 the result is 7.72.

On the other hand 7.025 CAN be exactly represented, and this would round to 7.03.

If this matters in your application, you could consider using the decimal type instead, which allows an exact representation of any decimal number ( up to the precision specified ).

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the issue, I just converted the values to decimal 16,9 first, so all of them have the same dec points before rounding off. Appreciate all your inputs! :)